# Is there any decluttering mode for Bing pushpins that are very close together?

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I have the following problem.
I have many pushpins on the Map and some of them either very close to each other or have the same coordinates and when I place them on the Map it looks like there is only one pushpin.

So, is it possible to display them in star like fashion or any way to indicate that in one point placed few pushpins?

PS: I have used MapQuest for a while and their API had such option, so when you configure pushpin with specific attribute and it overlaps with another pushpin on the Map, they just displayed away from original location indicating with  lines the original place.

Comment: Right now, you don't have this kind of features natively but I assume it could be done using combination of onviewchange event + custom HTML pushpin, at a certain zoom level, you change the pushpin to display various locations as a custom pushpin. I've started something a while ago as a module but it's not done, I'll see if I can share it soon.

Answer (score 0):

On Bing Maps REST Imagery API, you have the option to declutter the pushpins, see on the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

**Reference**

> declutterPins dcl Optional.
>
> Specifies whether to change the display of
>   overlapping pushpins so that they display separately on a map. One of
>   the following values: 1: Declutter pusphpin icons.
>
> 0 [default]: Do not declutter pushpin icons.
>
> Examples: declutter=1 dcl =1

**Sample Url**

And here is a sample Url:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/47.6156352,-122.2043549/12?pp=47.6156352,-122.2043549;;1&pp=47.612441,-122.204533;;2&dcl=1&key=BingMapsKey

Comment: Works perfect for static map, but doesn't work for pushpins that added dynamically to the map.

Comment: Yes as explained in my previous comment, it is not supported for interactive Map control right now. Since it was not clear what you were looking for, I've created this answer for Static Image (Bing Maps REST Imagery API).